# What's the difference between the exports array and exporting a module?

Tags: angular

I'm somewhat confused about the difference between declaring the export array and the exporting of the module class?

For example, I have a feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

My understanding is that if we were to import the TabsPageRoutingModule, say in AppModule, our root app now has the defined routes specified in this module as well as the exported RouterModule. If this is the case, why couldn't we declare RouterModule in the imports in the @NgModule decorator? Alternatively, why can't we export the RouterModule routes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm somewhat confused about the difference between declaring the export array and the exporting of the module class?

Modules that import another module aren't aware of all the dependency modules that are needed. So the child module can *export* secondary modules so that all of the dependencies will be imported when the child is imported.

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

This creates a child module using a static function. This child module does not contain the features of the `RouterModule`, but is used to configure the router with this route configuration.

> My understanding is that if we were to import the TabsPageRoutingModule, say in AppModule, our root app now has the defined routes specified in this module as well as the exported RouterModule.

It will only have the `RouterModule` imported into `AppModule`.

The route configuration is exposed via the dependency injection to the router. The `forChild()` function creates providers that hold the route configuration.

> If this is the case, why couldn't we declare RouterModule in the imports in the @NgModule decorator? Alternatively, why can't we export the RouterModule routes?

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the use of a separate module to define route configurations is purely optional. You can use `RouterModule.forChild(...)` inside your `AppModule` if you want.

You don't need to import `RouterModule` into `TabsPageRoutingModule` because it doesn't use it. That module only exists to define the providers that hold the route configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Some follow up questions: **Section** 1: Could you clarify what you mean by the child module not containing features of the RouterModule? The reason I ask is because the child module imports the RouterModule so this leads to me to think that it has the features of the Router Module but rather needs it to define the routes which it then exposes via dependency injection. **Section 3**: I suppose another way to ask the question is: What exactly am I exporting in export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}. Am I exporting what's defined in the metadata tag in this case?